# Hey, I am making put request using vue.js and axios to my controller but it is passing null to controller

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-6.0

[request object is null in my controller action method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/usRS7.png)As, mentioned before I am making put request using vue.js and axios to my asp.net core controller at backend for updating product but it is passing null to my controller's UpdateProduct action method.

I am getting updated product in request payload but it is null in my controller action method.
Here is my request payload:

```
{id: 19, name: "New It", description: "Product Description", value: "Rs.1.99"}
description
: 
"Product Description"
id
: 
19
name
: 
"New It"
value
: 
"Rs.1.99"
```

here is my vue.js code for updating product:

```
updateProduct() {
    this.loading = true;
    axios.put('/Admin/products', this.productModel)
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res.data);
            this.products.splice(this.objectIndex, 1, res.data);
        })
        .catch(err => { console.log(err); })
        .then(() => {
            this.loading = false;
        });
}
```

here is my Index.cshtml code:

```
@page
@model Shop.Ui.Pages.Admin.IndexModel
@{
}
@section scripts
    {
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.14/dist/vue.js"></script>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios@1.1.2/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/admin/main.js"></script>

}
<div id="app">
 <button v-on:click="getProducts">Get Products</button>
    <div>
        <p v-for="(product,index) in products">
            {{product.id}} - {{product.name}} - {{product.description}}
            <a @@click="editProduct(product,index)">Edit</a>
            <a @@click="deleteProduct(product.id)">Remove</a>
        </p>
    </div>
    
    <div>
        
        <input v-model="productModel.name"/> 
        <input v-model="productModel.description" />
        <input v-model.number="productModel.value" />
        <button @@click="createProduct" v-if="!productModel.id">Create Product</button>
        <button @@click="updateProduct" v-else>Update Product</button>
        
    </div>
</div>
```

My controller action method for updating product here, null is being passed to my request object.

```
        [HttpPut("products")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateProduct([FromBody] UpdateProduct.Request request) => Ok(await new UpdateProduct(_ctx).Do(request));
```

Here is my defination for UpdateProduct:

```
 public class UpdateProduct
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext _context;

        public UpdateProduct(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
        
        
        public async Task<Response> Do(Request request)
        {
            try
            {
                var product = _context.Products.Where(x => x.Id == request.Id).FirstOrDefault();

                product.Name = request.Name;
                product.Description = request.Description;
                product.Value = request.Value;

                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return new Response
                {
                    Id = product.Id,
                    Name = product.Name,
                    Description = product.Description,
                    Value = product.Value
                };
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Handle the exception here, you can log it or throw a custom exception.
                // For example, you can log the exception and then throw a custom exception.
                // Logging should be done using a proper logging library like Serilog or NLog.

                // Log the exception
                Console.WriteLine($"An error occurred: {ex.Message}");

                // You can re-throw a custom exception if needed.
                throw new ApplicationException("An error occurred while updating the product.");
            }
        }



        [Serializable]
        public class Request
        {
            public int Id {  get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Description { get; set; }
            public decimal Value { get; set; }
        }
        [Serializable]
        public class Response
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Description { get; set; }
            public decimal Value { get; set; }

        }
    }
}
```

Here is my code for program.cs:

```
// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => { options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
    options.EnableSensitiveDataLogging(); }) ; 
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
    options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
);
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy( "MyCorsPolicy",
                      builder =>
                      {
                          builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                          .AllowAnyMethod()
                          .AllowAnyHeader();
                      });
});
var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();


app.UseRouting();
app.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
app.UseCors("MyCorsPolicy");

app.UseAuthorization();


app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();
```

Please can anyone suggest me to resolve this error.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by _"it is passing null"_? Where do you see the `null` value? Use your browser's dev-tools _Network_ panel to check the actual request body, is it correct? You may need to set the NewtonSoft JSON options to handle property name case-insensitively (can't remember how to do that with Newton though, why aren't you using the built-in `System.Text.Json`?)

Comment: @Phil it is passing null to my action parameter in controller.In UpdateProduct action method request object is null.

Comment: FYI _`Rs.1.99`_ is **not** going to be a valid `decimal` type value. This is probably causing your binding to fail

Comment: @Phil i have thankyou for your response i have added screenshot to my question can you have look. what iam trying to say is that whole request object is null.

Comment: I have been investigating this problem for nearly 2 hours. The codes you have provided so far are all correct. [I also found an almost identical sample repo](https://github.com/xuzhg/Moutain/tree/e291deb0a1cb04a65b0c3ac408ff0c18bea6846e/Shop) and cannot reproduce your problem.

Comment: It's better to create a sample for us without any sensitive information, so that I can check the issue deeper.

Comment: And by the way, could you Press F12 and show the network information about click the Update Button.